# Django template can display array but not loop through it

Tags: django, list, loops, django-templates, render-to-response

In my view:

```
def scraped(request):
c = {}
response = example_response_output.html_response3
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html5lib')

titles = []
class_titles = soup.findAll("th", {"class" : "ddtitle"})
for class_title in class_titles:
    title = class_title.find("a")
    titles.append(title)

c.update({'titles': titles})

return render_to_response("src/scraped.html", c)
```

In my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ titles }}
    <br /><br/>
    {% for title in titles %}
        {{ title }}
        <br/>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

The output is:

```
 [<a href="/FAUPdad/bwckschd.p_disp_detail_sched?term_in=201508&amp;crn_in=86879">American Popular Music &amp; Cult - 86879 - MUH 2520 - 001</a>, <a href="/FAUPdad/bwckschd.p_disp_detail_sched?term_in=201508&amp;crn_in=82937">Music of Western Civilizatn 1 - 82937 - MUH 4211 - 001</a>, <a href="/FAUPdad/bwckschd.p_disp_detail_sched?term_in=201508&amp;crn_in=96784">Music of Western Civ 3 - 96784 - MUH 4371 - 001</a>, <a href="/FAUPdad/bwckschd.p_disp_detail_sched?term_in=201508&amp;crn_in=99697">20th-Century Music - 99697 - MUH 6375 - 001</a>]

[] 
[]
[]
[]
```

As you can see, {{ titles }}  prints out the list, as wanted.
However, when looping through the list it the individual elements are empty!

I can't figure out what's wrong, please help!

Thank you everyone :)

Comment: I have not worked with BeautifulSoup so I am just guessing. Can you try to change the line where you fill the list to titles.append(unicode(title)) to make sure your list contains strings.

Comment: worked like a charm! Thank you! Do you mind explaining what the problem was?

Comment: append(obj) will append the result of obj.__repr__() to the list. append(unicode(obj)) will append the result of obj.__unicode__() to the list. In the case of the soup object __repr__ will not return a unicode representation of the object but something else, which django then will refuse to loop through.